# Ratio of two sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry

**Question**

OAB is a triangle

[image]

OPM and APN are straight lines
M is the midpoint of AB

$OP:PM = 3:2$

Work out the ratio of $ON:OB$

I'm trying to work out the ratio of `ON:NB` but I can't seem to find the answer. Any help will be useful. Thanks

Comment: The image is blurry.

Comment: My apologies. I've updated the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Note that the triangles AON and ANM share the same base line AN and use the ratios below

$$\frac32 = \frac{OP}{PM}=\frac{Area_{AON}}{Area_{ANM}} = 
\frac{\frac{ON}{OB}Area_{ABC}}{\frac12 \frac{NB}{OB}Area_{ABC}}
=2\frac{ON}{NB}$$

Thus,

$$\frac{ON}{NB} = \frac34$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.